# Efficient calculation of inter-PUF and intra-PUF Hamming Distance

Tags: python, numpy, hamming-distance

My application is data analysis for [Physical Unclonable Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_unclonable_function) (PUFs). More specifically, I am working with weak N-bit PUF arrays meaning each array produces a single N-bit key every time it is evaluated. There are P PUF arrays. I want to examine the two desired properties of *uniqueness* and *repeatability* by calculating the inter-PUF and intra-PUF Hamming distances respectively.

The PUF keys are read M times for each array at X different environmental conditions producing a data set of P*X NumPy arrays of shape (N,M). I am aware of the [curse of dimensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality) which suggests to me that I need to calculate the Hamming distance for every pair of keys. This would require (P * X * M) choose 2 operations. For example, if I had 1000 arrays each read 1000 times at 12 operating conditions that would produce 12E6 N-bit PUF values and there would be 12E6 choose 2 combinations to calculate which is over 7E13 operations.

Can the problem be simplified by knowledge that the intra-PUF Hamming distances are very small (~<10%) compared to the inter-PUF Hamming distances (~50%)? I don't need to check every possible inter-PUF distance. But I am still facing (X * M) choose 2 (eg: ~72E6) combinations for each array.

Ultimately I only need to know the maximum intra-PUF Hamming distance for each array between the X different environmental conditions. Is there anything I can exploit, like if I calculate the maximally spaced pair within a single array at a single environmental condition which would be the maximum of M choose 2 Hamming Distances, can I check only this pair against the readouts at different environmental conditions?

Maybe what I am asking is whether there are any properties of locally clustered data in high dimensionality that I can exploit?

Comment: This looks a lot like a problem that belongs in a 'mathematics' forum rather than a Python one.  I think you're on the right track by identifying that the initial solution is, computationally, too large. Perhaps you can figure out your new algorithm, calculate that it _does_ have reasonable runtime and then edit your question to give simple Python code or pseudocode if you still need help with Python-related details.